# How to integrate TCPDF?

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf

I wanted to add TCPDF to codeigniter so i downloaded TCPDF from [TCPDF Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/files/) and created a file in /libraries/Pdf.php as such

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/tcpdf/tcpdf.php';

class Pdf extends TCPDF
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

and used it as such in controller

```
function pdfTest(){

        $this->load->library("Pdf");
        $pdf = new Pdf('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
        $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
            // Add a page
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $html = "<h1>Test Page</h1>";
            $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
            $pdf->Output();
        }
```

But it gives me below error

```
TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file
```

What could be the reason of the error and how can I solve it? I have searched allot but couldn't find a solution. 
Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: Rather than output the PDF, try to place an exit;(so before the $pdf->Output(); ) and check for any data that might have been placed. Maybe its an error debug message or whatelse that has been sent first.

Comment: I placed `exit;` before `$pdf->Output();` but their is no error displayed. Debugging is ON in both php and codeigniter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found the answer I placed `ob_clean();` before `$pdf->Output('test.pdf','I');` That solved the issue. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: A bit too late to answer this but it was the BOM elements which was creating an issue. Managed to remove all BOM elements and now its working fine without `ob_clean();` could be helpful for anyone refering this in future.

Answer (score 3):

make sure not to have whitespace before `<?php` and after `?>`
or
Just use `ob_start();` at the top of the page.

Comment: I would have voted you up but I need reputation 15 to vote up.

Answer (score 2):

This error indicates that already some error or output is displayed or echoed before creating pdf. Please check if you have printed anything.